# Show Opponent's Score (Multiplayer/GameKit) - Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I have it set up so it sends the player's score to the opponents's screen so they can see what their score is, but it never updates the value. Any ideas?

```
typedef enum
{
    kMessageTypeRandomNumber = 0,
    kMessageTypeScore,
} MessageType;

typedef struct
{
    Message message;
    int score;
} MessageScore;

@interface GSMultiplayer : CCLayer <GCHelperDelegate>
{
    CCLabelTTF *oppScoreLabel;

    uint32_t ourRandom;
    BOOL receivedRandom;
}
--------------------------------------------
- (void)sendScore
{
    CCLOG(@"Sent Score");
    int oppScore = score;

    MessageScore message;
    message.message.messageType = kMessageTypeScore;
    message.score = oppScore;
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&message length:sizeof(MessageScore)];
    [self sendData:data];
}

- (void)tryStartGame
{
    if (isPlayer1 && gameState == kGameStateWaitingForStart)
    {
        [self setGameState:kGameStateActive];
        [self sendGameBegin];
    }

    [self sendScore];
}

- (void)matchStarted
{    
    CCLOG(@"Match started");        
    if (receivedRandom)
    {
        [self setGameState:kGameStateWaitingForStart];
    } else {
        [self setGameState:kGameStateWaitingForRandomNumber];
    }
    [self sendRandomNumber];
    [self tryStartGame];
}

- (void)match:(GKMatch *)match didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromPlayer:(NSString *)playerID
{
    Message *message = (Message *) [data bytes];

    if (message->messageType == kMessageTypeScore)
    {
        CCLOG(@"Score Received");

        [scoreLabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %d", score]];
        }
    }
}
```

Also, score is globally delcared from the main "GameScene". I am very new to multiplayer so help is greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of the score yourself and add a layer to display the score.. after player changes scene, send the score to gamecenter?

Is your game using gamekit? If yes, you might wan to look at an example in a game called Infinight.. there is a lite version in the App store.. It has gamecenter multiplayer in it.. Just play it with friends and see how it works.. It also sends score to gamecenter after playing..

in your send data function:

```
   msg.oppScore = score;
            NSData *packet = [NSData dataWithBytes:&msg length:sizeof(charInfo)];


            [sharedData.myMatch sendDataToAllPlayers: packet withDataMode: GKMatchSendDataUnreliable error:&error];
```

sharedData.myMatch is suppose to be the GKMatch that you are suppose to reference to when the game starts..

Comment: I am keeping track of the score already and the layer is showing the player's score on the screen, but I need the opponents score to show on the player's screen

Comment: oh.. send score over.. Since you can send data to each other, you can send opp score as well..

Comment: How do I do that? That's what I'm asking

Comment: Are you using the bluetooth version or over the wireless?

Comment: I'm using Game Center, so I think that is over the internet

Comment: Hmm.. U mean u have a multiplayer game without sending data to each other? Means you do not have: - (void)match:(GKMatch *)match didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromPlayer:(NSString *)playerID?

Comment: I do have that(i put my code in the question). But, that code will not show my score on the opponents screen. Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?